# Internationalizing .xib files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, menu, internationalization, osx-mountain-lion, xib

I have a simple Mac app that I want to internationalize. I know how to use `NSLocalizedString` etc., and this seems very convenient and well thought out.

However, I also need to internationalize a `.xib` file in my project. I found [this post](http://swemoney.com/post/5185142028/adding-internationalization-to-xib-files-in-xcode-4) about the process.

I tried it out, and it works, but strikes me as an extremely bad idea. Is there really no better way? What following the post produces is a bunch of copies of the .xib file, one for each language:

[image]

This works fine, until you decide to change an element in the interface, because then you have to go to each language, and change the element in every single one.

Is there a better way to internationalize the xib files?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use "base internationalization". It allows you to internationalize the strings without messing with the nib files.

However, it requires iOS 6, and it works best when used with Autolayout.

There is a section about base internationalizationin the handy [Internationalize Your App Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html).

If you need to support iOS 5 you have to use your way. Or, as I prefer it, connect all UIViews to a IBOutlet and replace all texts in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually for a Mac app, not iOS. Edited now to make that clear

Comment: If you try to run an app with Base Internationalization on iOS5 will the app crash or simply not make use of the translations/internationalizations?